# Splitting strain gauge signal before amplification

Tags: sensor, signal-processing

I have a strain gauge full bridge force sensor with 3mV/V sensitivity and power it with 10 V excitation, giving up to 30 mV output. Normally the output is connected to a 3rd party device's strain gauge input (call it device "X"). That device can't plot the force during measurement, so I want to show the real time data in a different device. That is why I need to get the signal. I have 2 ideas:

Option 1:
Split the strain gauge's raw output signal, for example with a [device like this](http://www.prelectronics.com/?altTemplate=showproduct&id=2314). Splitted signal 1 goes to device X. Splitted signal 2 goes to my own device.

Option 2:
Get an external strain gauge amplifier, scale signal to 10 V, and split 10 V signal afterwards, as in option 1. The device X also has a +-10 V input, so no problem here.

I think option 2 is better. But I really want to understand HOW the strain gauge output is affected by splitting the signal as in option 1. I know that the splitter is pure analog, no A/D conversion is happening.
How does a splitter possibly work? Is it creating a parallel circuit? Then I assume that it would not increase the load on the strain gauge output, hence having no bad effect. But if the splitter would be somehow connected serially only, I think that the total resistance increases and I am going to measure a lower voltage in device X. Is it conceptually much different splitting a strain gauge signal in contrast to a potentiometer signal (for example from a travel sensor)? Could you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 1):

If you just have the one strain gauge and you are alright with whatever gain your selected instrumentation amp affords you I would go with Andy aka's suggestion.  There are some really nice old Burr-Brown (TI bought them a long time ago) instrumentation amps for this sort of thing that have adjustable gain via a resistor and can get you a nice large scaled single-ended voltage to measure instead of the small differential voltage.  For example:

https://www.digikey.com/short/3vpvh7

If you have more than one strain gauge, or you just want more design detail control, you could instead try something like what's suggested here:

https://eewiki.net/display/Motley/Analog+Bits+-+Analog+Combinator+Circuit+for+Load+Cells

Answer (score 0):

An instrumentation amplifier (InAmp) has a high impedance input and is the turn-to device when measuring strain gauge bridges. It takes no appreciable measurement current from the bridge and you would hardly know it is there.

More than likely the 3rd party device uses an InAmp and, there is no difficulty in you using an InAmp in parallel i.e. both measuring the same bridge output. You just have to make sure that the bridge output voltage swing (a few milli volts centred at 5 volts) is compatible with your InAmp i.e. you need to choose an InAmp that can work from your 10 volt excitation supply a bit like this configuration: -

[image]

You should be able to power your InAmp from the reference 10 volt supply and 0 volts. Most InAmps I use can do this such as the AD8221.

> I have 2 ideas

Without digging around looking for specifications for splitter it's difficult to say. If you can provide more technical info then great, but if you can't just go for an InAmp.

Comment: Makes sense. But I can't follow your point that the output voltage swings around 5 V. Okay, how a strain gauge works and considering the drawing, it is clear what you mean. But all the data sheets of a strain gauge sensor say for example 3mV/V, so 10 V excitation I get 30 mV. This is the absolute voltage, nothing relative. How does this relate? On a sidenote, I am not going to use a bare bones inamp. We are a mechanical dep., not an electrics, and we need to buy from suppliers, not build our own.

Comment: No, it's not the absolute voltage relative to ground - +/-30 mV is the differential voltage you get. Both outputs of the bridge will still be centred about 5 volts but one will be 5 volts +15 mV and the other will be 5 volts - 15 mV. This is an EE site and I only recommend EE solutions that make sense to EE guys. If you are looking for a buying recommendation then take note that this is not a shopping site - it's in the rules.

Comment: Or most likely the 30 mV is relative but only an informative value that is useful for the DAQ device. So I now think as a first step I should try to connect the signals in parallel to a differential amplifier at 5 V, and use a scope to see what's happening... EDIT: Just wrote that as you were posting, too. Heck, this is not a shopping site, but what better place to get information than here where the experts are? I am trying to understand, and this is what a Q&A site is for.

Comment: Don't forget that your differential amplifier may have too small an input impedance - this is why I recommended IAs and yes, you can get built up IAs on PCBs and you should consider powering it from your 10 volt supply.

Comment: I now thought that the diff amp would be made of an IA.

Comment: Shopping: I have recommended an IA and in particular the AD8221 but this is just an example (but a pretty good one). This site is for EE design issues and there are many Q&As suitable that don't delve into asking for suitable parts. Shopping recommendations do not stand the rigours of time.

Comment: In the end it is still about the design of my solution, just on another level than typical for this site, maybe ;) I did not ask for shopping advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually with the splitting device you won't get any good result. You would need a differential input signal DAQ. The best you can try is to use a two channel scope and subtract both signals to get the difference. Keep also in mind that these devices output very small voltage, they do need an amplifier or even more stages of amplifiers. Temperature stability, drift, etc can be an issue. With attaching a parallel measuring device, you will certainly add some noise to the cell output.

As for second option: A good stable na fast amplifier is expensive, a good solution is some front end with ADC tailored for the application. Adding external amplifier will certainly make your signal acquisition worse than that you have.

You can however use an instrumentation amplifier for strain gauge and second for the displacement sensor and hook to scope to get X-Y curve. When testing press/displacement you should get almost identical results for scope and your DAQ.

Comment: Why exactly won't the splitter provide good results? And what do you mean by expensive? We plan to spend 1k for making that plot work... that includes also a little display tablet, not only the measurement devices. I keep in mind that we need amplifiers. My question talks about that as well. And the linked splitter is at least galvanically isolated so I hoped it won't produce noise.

Comment: Galvanically isolated amplifier is slow and inaccurate. Still there is a physical connection on the cell. The only solution is to use an amplifier with ADC and only the digital signal is then transferred trough isolation barrier. Your proposed device as an general purpose DC signal isolator, not an instrumentation amplifier with integrated ADC. Anyway, what is the purpose of having two DAQ systems on the same load cell?

Comment: The purpose is just that the device X does some other stuff that my display is not trying to solve again. I just want to add that missing feature. Why not replace device X? Because it is a running system, and probably much more expensive...

Comment: Analog devices produce some eval boards that are complete front end with ADC . But you would need an electro engineer.  First step is to determine the excitation voltage of the device-X https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/eval-adicup360/hardware/cn0216